# Building QT 5 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

Following the normal installation procedures:

```
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -confirm-license 
make
make docs
make install docs
```

I ended up with some ~12GB size in the folder where I extracted my `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0-alpha.tar.gz` for Ubuntu.

I deleted that build and tried

```
./configure -prefix /usr/local/qt-5.6.0-alpha/ -opensource\
-confirm-license -developer-build
make
make install
```

followed by

```
make docs
make install docs
```

This time, just before trying to install docs, my installation folder (under `/usr/local`) and my source folder were normal sizes before trying to install docs. After building and installing docs, my source folder was **20 GB**, and i noticed a lot of **HEAVY** `src` and `test` folders under each first level directory in my installation folder.

I don't know where to find QT creater under the build too. A file search was futile.

Does anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is your question? 'make install docs' will not install docs. It will build & install 'all', then generate docs.

Comment: What i want is to have the documentation on my computer. And, i would like ot to be stored in a prefered location, the way i like to install **"big things"** under `/usr/local/`      with that, please differentiate the terms **generate docs** and **install docs** for me.  English is not a first language for most of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, For not including test, add `-nomake tests` to configure command.

You can do a `make clean` after compiling to save a lot of space.

Compiling QT from source does not come with QT Creator. You have to install it separately and follow this procedure to use it with your compiled Qt.

Download Qt Creator: http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ and install it.

1. Start Qt Creator
2. Go to Tools, Options
3. Select Build and Run from the list on the left.
4. Go to "Qt Versions" tab
5. Click on "Add" and select qmake from the folder where your bin in qtbase
6. Click "Apply"
7. Go to "Kits" tab
8. Click "Add"
9. Give it a name, choose the appropriate compiler
10. Click OK

Comment: I left the tests on because i thought they would help the build to test itself. +1 for giving part of the solution. How do i get the documentation onto my computer please.

Comment: additionally, I downloaded a file from the link you provided. can it let me download **Strictly QT-Creator**. I already have an old version installed from **synaptic** [Ubuntu] but I want to have the **latest**

Comment: You should already have the documentation installed after running `make docs`. By default, it install in `qt5/qtbase/doc/` or to the directory set to qmake's  `QT_INSTALL_DOCS` variable.
https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Documentation

Comment: You can uninstall the old Qt Creator you have. 
For 64 bit: 
http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/3.5/3.5.0/qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-3.5.0.run

For 32 bit:
 http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/3.5/3.5.0/qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86-3.5.0.run
These are strictly just QT creators and the latest.

Comment: there's quite a bit of QT from the past. do you know how safe it is to remove all the old QT stuff, e.g, QT4.   I one time broke my system trying to remove python.

Comment: the answers are partial. I have an idea when you say **qmake's QT_INSTALL_DOCS variable**. it would be nice if you divulged exactly what i have to do to **~/.config/Trolltech/qmake.conf** or anything else.